# What is this href?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am trying to understand this particular link. I suspect it launches some sort of Java script, but I am not sure. What I want at the end of the day is to extract the URL.

The html tag is this:

```
<a href="#" 
    onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 
        'function' {jsfcljs(document.getElementById('resultadoForm'),
    {'resultado:0:j_id234':'resultado:0:j_id234'},'');}
    return false">
        11024968
</a>
```

And this is reached by going to `http://www.dataescolabrasil.inep.gov.br/dataEscolaBrasil/home.seam`, typing "11024968" in "Código" and then submitting the form ("Pesquisar"). The link shown above is for "11024968".

Also,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">function dpf(f) {var adp = f.adp;if (adp != null) {for (var i = 0;i < adp.length;i++) {f.removeChild(adp[i]);}}};function apf(f, pvp) {var adp = new Array();f.adp = adp;var i = 0;for (k in pvp) {var p = document.createElement("input");p.type = "hidden";p.name = k;p.value = pvp[k];f.appendChild(p);adp[i++] = p;}};function jsfcljs(f, pvp, t) {apf(f, pvp);var ft = f.target;if (t) {f.target = t;}f.submit();f.target = ft;dpf(f);};</script>
```

So, I'd grateful if anyone could explain how to follow (or extract) the url whose text is "11024968".

Comment: Edited to include the `jsfcljs()` function, as @rekire said.

Comment: It seems that the parameters of the JSON are appended to the formular. The target is set to the url itself ("") and after submit the parameters are removed and the target is reset to its original value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link points to an empty anchor. This is commonly used for JavaScript handled links. So if your JavaScript fails just the hash tag is added to the current url.

The magic happens in your code in the `jsfcljs()` JavaScript function. Without the code we cannot say more just now.

Let us reformat the code and give them better names:

```
function dpf(f) {                  // let's rename this to removeParameters
    var adp = f.adp;               // element store from apf (addParameters)
    if(adp != null) {              // check if the parematers needs to be removed
        for(var i=0; i<adp.length; i++) { // interates thrue the known paramters
            f.removeChild(adp[i]); // removes a child
        }
    }
};
function apf(f, pvp) { // let's rename this to addParameters
    var adp = new Array();
    f.adp = adp;
    var i = 0;
    for(k in pvp) { // iterates thrue the json structure
        // appends all parameters from the json structure to the
        // element store (apd) and to the given formular (f)
        var p = document.createElement("input");
        p.type = "hidden";
        p.name = k;
        p.value = pvp[k];
        f.appendChild(p);
        adp[i++] = p;
    }
};
function jsfcljs(f, pvp, t) { // let's rename this to postJsonData
    apf(f, pvp);              // add paramaters
    var ft = f.target;        // store orginal target
    if(t) {
        f.target = t;         // set new target if given
    }
    f.submit();               // submit the form
    f.target = ft;            // restore target
    dpf(f);                   // remove added parameters
};
```

Comment: Thanks @rekire. I've edited my question so to include the `jsfcljs()` function.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. My knowledge of Java is non-existent though. Anyway, given that my ultimate goal is to crawl this website, I guess I need something like Selenium (was using mechanize in python before). Any thought, always appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Please remember allways that you need a permission to use data from other domains. Also note that Java and JavaScript are totally different languages. Just the syntax is almost the same like in C like languages.